# Activity with dialog theme not shown as dialog

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am working on an Android project and I creating an activity that should use a dialog theme, but it's not displaying correctly.

Below is my activities layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.DialogWindowTitle"/>
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/dialog_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@android:style/DeviceDefault.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnCopyToClipbard"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Copy to Clipboard"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"/>
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close"
            style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Button.Borderless"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Below is how my activity is defined

```
<activity
            android:name=".CustomAlertDialogActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        </activity>
```

The activity class is as follows

```
public class CustomAlertDialogActivity extends BaseActionBarActivity
{
    TextView txtDialogTitle;
    TextView txtDialogMessage;
    Bundle bundle;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);

        txtDialogTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_title);
        txtDialogMessage = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.dialog_message);

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            txtDialogTitle.setText("An error occurred");
            txtDialogMessage.setText("No error was specified");
            return;
        }
        txtDialogTitle.setText(bundle.getString(CustomAlertDialog.DIALOG_TITLE));
        txtDialogMessage.setText(bundle.getString(CustomAlertDialog.DIALOG_MESSAGE));
    }
}
```

`BaseActionBarActivity` is my own class which extends `AppCompatActivity`

Below is how my alert dialog is shown

[image: Activity screenshot]

In case it makes any difference this activity is within a library project which is being included into my app.

Comment: Could you include your java class in the question please?

Comment: @Rick I've added my java class to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the your `Activity` looks for me:
[image]
[image]
(Android 6.0 and Android 4.4 respectively)

To test, I just copied your code into an empty project and, as you see, it works (even though it requires some UI polishing).

My best guess is that you unintentionally do `setTheme()`, etc. somewhere in super-class `BaseActionBarActivity`. So as a step 1, **replace `BaseActionBarActivity` with `AppCompatActivity`** and see, if it changes anything.

Comment: You were right, my BaseActionBarActivity had setTheme() I forgot about that, wrote that class quite a while ago.